# gvim not operator in substitute command

Tags: regex, vim

I've got a number of files that look like the one below:

```
HR0100001012010093001
EF0000120100930000000
HR0200001012010093001
EF0000120100930000000
HR0900001012010093001
EF000012010093000000
HR1000001012010093001
EF000012010093000000
HR1100001012010093001
text
EF000012010093000000
HR1200001012010093001
EF000012010093000000
HR1300001012010093001
EF000012010093000000
HR0100001012010093001
text
EF0000120100930000000
HR2000001012010093001
EF000012010093000000
HR2200001012010093001
EF000012010093000000
```

I'd like to strip off all the blocks starting with HRxx and ending with EF* except for those starting with HR01, i.e. I'd like to get the result below:

```
HR0100001012010093001
EF0000120100930000000
HR0100001012010093001
text
EF0000120100930000000
```

Using the command below:

```
:%s/HR01\_.\{-}EF.*$//g
```

I am able to DELETE the lines I'm searching for; as a final step, I'd like to use the "Not Operator" to reverse the result thus getting the lines I actually need. Unfortunately I don't understand how to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Francesco

Answer (score 2):

Solution found:

```
%s/HR\(01\)\@!\_.\{-}EF.*$//g
```